# Create documentation notebook for Shiny app files

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, r-markdown

I have a Shiny app with 3 R files (ui.r, server.r and global.r)

For normal .R documents I can just embed code like this:

```
#' ---
#' title: "User Interface for My Awesome App"
#' author: "Serban Tanasa"
#' date: "Current Version Updated - 2015.07.09"
#' output: html_document
#' ---
```

and so on and so forth, and assuming I've sprinkled comments around the whole script, I can press the handy "Compile Notebook" button in RStudio-Server:

[image]

...and compile it into a decent documentation. With the shiny app however, trying to compile the ui i get the following error.

```
output file: ui.knit.md

Error: path for html_dependency not provided
Execution halted
```

Is there some way to get around this?

This is for R 3.2.1, with RStudio Server Version 0.98.1103, and Shiny 0.12.0

Comment: Please let me know if there's some vital information I'm failing to provide, I'll be happy to do so. Dunno how to produce a replicable example in this case.

Comment: More accurately, you can reproduce the situation by starting a new shiny app, and trying to "Compile notebook" on the working sample app Rstudio autogenerates on shiny app project creation.

Answer (score 1):

Shiny is meant to be run as an application, not to be compiled into a document, I don't think that button is designed to work with Shiny files.